# String remove from n-th last seperator to the end

Tags: r, string, split, tail, separator

I have the following string:

```
data_string = c("Aa_Bbbbb_0_ID1",
                "Aa_Bbbbb_0_ID2",
                "Aa_Bbbbb_0_ID3",
                "Ccccc_D_EEE_0_ID1")
```

I just wanted to split all the string to have these results:

```
"Aa_Bbbbb"
"Aa_Bbbbb"
"Aa_Bbbbb"
"Ccccc_D_EEE"
```

So basically, I'm looking for a function which take data_string, set a separator, and take the split position :

```
remove_tail(data_table, sep = '_', del = 2)
```

only removing the tail from 2nd last separator to the end of the string (not split all the string)

Comment: Why not split on `"_"`, then paste back first 2? Or split on `"_0_"` ?

Comment: My example was not correct. I just corrected it; you can see your first solution doesn't work if there is `"A_B_C_D_0_ID3"`.  yeah spli on `"_0_" ` works fine but I'm not sure if I will always have this flag in the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below:

```
# split on "_" then paste back removing last 2
sapply(strsplit(data_string, "_", fixed = TRUE),
       function(i) paste(head(i, -2), collapse = "_"))
```

We can make our own function:

```
# custom function
remove_tail <- function(x, sep = "_", del = 2){
  sapply(strsplit(x, split = sep, fixed = TRUE),
         function(i) paste(head(i, -del), collapse = sep))
  }

remove_tail(data_string, sep = '_', del = 2)
# [1] "Aa_Bbbbb"    "Aa_Bbbbb"    "Aa_Bbbbb"    "Ccccc_D_EEE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `gsub`

`gsub("_0_.*","",data_string)`

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `sub` tp match the `_` followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) and the rest of the characters, replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub("_\\d+.*", "", data_string)
#[1] "Aa_Bbbbb"    "Aa_Bbbbb"    "Aa_Bbbbb"    "Ccccc_D_EEE"
```